# Is Death Domain Evil?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, alignment

I am looking to create a cleric in e5 DnD. I was wondering if it is possible, to make a neutral good cleric, that still uses Death Domain.

My idea was, that he sheperds the souls of the dead to their corresponding plane (of death?). That would be a good deed.

Comment: What about this character and this build presents a problem you are trying to solve? Please consult the material provided in the [tour] and consider how to create a question that lends itself to a "best" answer.  This site handles questions better, and provides better answers, [when the questions fit the guidelines provided](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).